# How to send specific set of logs from systemd journals logs to cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, systemd

I use `journalctl -fu service` to see the logs of a specific service. Is possible to sent systemd journal logs to cloudwatch logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gist ([Setting up aws log agent to send journalctl from DC/OS logs to Amazon Log Service)](https://gist.github.com/RichardHightower/318971f60e2dd44ef71027ce5ea2cb05) is what you are looking for.

Basically setup a [EC2 utility daemon](https://github.com/saymedia/journald-cloudwatch-logs) process to forward journald logs to AWS CloudWatch.